# Style doesn't apply to StackPanel items in ListView - Windows Universal

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, margin, datatemplate

I have created a listview with databinding and a "Itemstemplate" which takes a "Datatemplate" where I have a Stackpannel but the style doesn't apply to the stackpannel, there is no space between the textblocks in the stackpannel:

```
 <ListView Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Gray" >
                    <StackPanel.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="margintextblock">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,0,0"/>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Resources>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource listviewtextblock}" Text="{Binding Path=Firstname}" Foreground="Gold"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource listviewtextblock}" Text="{Binding Path=Lastname}" Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource listviewtextblock}" Text="{Binding Path=Id}" Foreground="OrangeRed"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

So what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `x:Key="margintextblock"` because of this the style doesn't apply automatically to the TextBlocks

By setting the x:Key property on a style, you are telling WPF that you only want to use this style when you explicitly reference it on a specific control.

Take a look on [this tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/using-styles/)

**EDITED**

And you also have another problem - you are setting style for you TextBlocks `Style="{StaticResource listviewtextblock}"`

In this case what you have to do is inherit StackPanel TextBlock style from listviewtextblock style

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource listviewtextblock}">
         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,0,0"/>
     </Style>
 </StackPanel.Resources>
```

And remove style `Style="{StaticResource listviewtextblock}"` from TextBlocks

you code should looks like this

```
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Gray" >
                    <StackPanel.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource listviewtextblock}" >
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,0,0"/>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Resources>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Firstname}" Foreground="Gold"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Lastname}" Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}" Foreground="OrangeRed"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```